# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in Joomla when using another user account

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, access-denied

I'm working on a hosting which currently have Joomla installed.
I want to test my new page which doesn't run over Joomla, neither Wordpress, neither any other CMS, It is just php code from scratch.

I created a new folder on the hosting but when I try to access via:

myhosting.com/mynewfolder/index.php

I get the next error

Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)

...but, the problem is that I'm not using root user. I'm trying to connect to another database which is in another server with a different username, not "root". I'm trying to connect using the next code, which works perfectly in my localhost:

```
$conn =  mysql_connect('external-hosting-on-another-server.com', 'username-not-root', 'password');
```

I'm pretty sure that hosting accepts external connections because, as I said, It works on my localhost.

I don't understand why it is trying to connect using a "root" user.
I think it has something to do with Joomla, but I'm not sure.

Maybe if I delete all Joomla files in the hosting and upload only my files it will work, do you think?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check the complete error-message. Is this line of code really the one mentioned in the error-message? Any PHP-opcode-caches installed?

Comment: The message I get is this: Can't coneeeeect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). Note that I added many "ee" to make sure the error is generating in my code and not in any other Joomla file. So, my code can't connect to my database because it's trying to connect using root user when it shouldn't

Comment: Do you require / include any files? Maybe the problem could be here. Also maybe you see old error message (due to mod_expires apache plugin). Anyway, the first thing I would try is to use `mysqli_connect` except for `mysql_connect`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using include files and they are already up. I'm sure that is my code which is sending error because I added many "eeee" ("Can't coneeeeeect"). (Maybe it's a dumb way to test it but I couldn't think in other option)

Comment: Finally I solved it. My hosting don't resolve host names, so I used IP instead and it worked! Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Does user have privileges of this database? You must to give it privileges about this database. From your database.

Try it, I believe that is this. Here I put the sentence that I use:

```
$con = mysql_connect("host","user","pass") or die ("Could not connect to database");

var_dump($con);
```

If var_dump($con) return resulset, is connected to database.